# Substrings or split methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have a simple problem that I think I need help with. So, I have a function that accepts a string in this format

`"1. Crowe, Velvet (LoC), 2. Hume, Eleanor (Ext), 4. Shigure, Rokurou (DmN), 10. Mayvin, Magilou (MgC)"` without the quotation marks.

Basically, a list of person's names with rank number.

What I want is to split them such that I will get the ff result:

```js
[
   "1. Crowe, Velvet (LoC)", 
   "2. Hume, Eleanor (Ext)", 
   "4. Shigure, Rokurou (DmN)",
   "10. Mayvin, Magilou (MgC)"
]
```

Is there a way to do that? I used `split()` method but it splits the string every time it sees an occurrence of the comma.

Comment: Is the format for each item always `<number>. <text>, <text> (<text>)`?

Comment: @NickParsons, yes. It's always like that

Comment: hacky and probably not best. split by ("),") and map result array and add ")" to each element. `"1. Crowe, Velvet (LoC), 2. Hume, Eleanor (Ext), 4. Shigure, Rokurou (DmN), 10. Mayvin, Magilou (MgC)".split("),").map(el => el+")")`

Comment: @Hansel actually no the last element breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split using a regular expression `/(?<=\)),\s/`:

```js
const str = "1. Crowe, Velvet (LoC), 2. Hume, Eleanor (Ext), 4. Shigure, Rokurou (DmN), 10. Mayvin, Magilou (MgC)";
const res = str.split(/(?<=\)),\s/);
console.log(res);
```

This will split on `),`  as suggested by [cmgchess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13583510/cmgchess) in the comments. The issue with splitting based on a string is that it removes some of the characters you want to keep. Instead, by using a regular expression, you can use `(?<=\))` (here `?<=` is called a *positive lookbehind*) to match and keep the `)` in the resulting split element. The `,\s` then splits based on a comma followed by a space (`\s`).

You could also use the following regex with `.match()` which is a little more robust, but may need to be updated depending on the text that can come after your number/rank:

```
/\d+\.\s\w+,\s\w+\s\(\w+\)/g
```

The above performs:

- `\d+\.`: Will match one or more (`+`) digits followed by a dot
- `\s`: Match a whitespace character
- `\w+,`: Match one of more (`+`) word-characters (`\w`) followed by a comma `,`
- `\s`: Matches a space
- `\(\w+\)`: Match word characters surrounded by parentheses `(` `)`
- `/g`: Global flag to match the sequences for all occurrences in the string

```js
const str = "1. Crowe, Velvet (LoC), 2. Hume, Eleanor (Ext), 4. Shigure, Rokurou (DmN), 10. Mayvin, Magilou (MgC)";
const res = str.match(/\d+\.\s\w+,\s\w+\s\(\w+\)/g);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little improvement of `@cmgchess`'s answer (add `trim` method to remove unnecessary spaces):

```js
const getUsers = (str) => {
    const users = str.split('),').map(x => x.trim() + ')');
    users[users.length - 1] = users[users.length - 1].replace('))', ')');

    return users;
}

console.log(getUsers("1. Crowe, Velvet (LoC), 2. Hume, Eleanor (Ext), 4. Shigure, Rokurou (DmN), 10. Mayvin, Magilou (MgC)"));
```

Comment: actually my answer is not correct check the last element. maybe have to apply regex

Comment: Ah, there is an extra ")" at the last element. That was what @cmgchess meant by "the last element breaks".

Comment: Sorry guys, now I replace extra `)`